# iOS UICollectionView navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to navigate around my app. But i'm a little lost.

I have a UIViewController that loads some data, then displays the data in a CollectionView. Then I have another UIViewController for the detailed view. I then trigger a segue to go to it, I pass the data etc.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailViewSeque", sender: nil)
```

But the part i'm lost on is getting back to my main view, if I just trigger another segue then it loads all the data / view again. The data has already been loaded once, I really don't want to keep loading it.

I feel like I'm doing things wrong, that theres some super obvious way to handle this scenario.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you say "load" do you mean pull from the network or a database? If so then you should keep the data around in your first UIViewController as a variable. 
If by "lead" you mean create a UIViewController from a storyboard that is a tiny cost that doesn't delay your app at all

Comment: @Kevin I'm loading JSON from a server, it takes around 1.3 - 1.5 seconds. so it's quite a large cost unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase your needs "I have data that I need to keep around somewhere that isn't associated with a view controller".

You have a few options here. Your goal is basically to store it somewhere that isn't going to go out of memory.
The `AppDelegate` gets used for this purpose a lot but [Singleton](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) variable works as well.

I would personally create a singleton, say `CatPictureRetriever` with

```
private let _CatPictureRetriever SharedInstance = CatPictureRetriever()

class CatPictureRetriever {
    static let sharedInstance = CatPictureRetriever()

    var catPictures : NSArray?;

    func gimmeCatPictures -> NSArray? {
        return catPictures
    }
}
```

Now you can get your pictures though your CatPictureRetriever anywhere

```
var pictures = CatPictureRetriever.sharedInstance.gimmeCatPictures()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is good situation to use an *unwind segue* (for more information: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)). Here's how to setup one up:

Firstly, create an `@IBAction` in the view controller you want to segue **to**, that takes a `UIStoryboardSegue` as its only argument. For example:

```
@IBAction func unwindToHere(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // If you need you have access to the previous view controller 
    // through the segue object.
}
```

Secondly, you need to create the unwind segue in IB. To do this ctrl-drag from the view controller you want to segue **from**, to *Exit* and select the `unwindToHere` method:

[image]

Thirdly, you need to give your segue and identifier. To do this select your segue (see below - your segue will not be visible like normal segues); then use the Attribute Editor to give your segue an identifier.

[image]

Now you can use your segue. On the view controller you want to segue from, call:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourID", sender: self)
```